# Flutter - Dart - remove hidden character from String input

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I'm trying to compare 2 strings, however my comparison always fails.
For reference, the one string is a filename I'm getting from the phones storage and it look like it ends with an apostrophe, although its not visible anywhere.

Please consider the following dart code:

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  const Utf8Codec utf8 = Utf8Codec();
  
String input = 'chatnum.txt';
String stringwithapostrophe = 'chatnum.txt\'';
  
  String compInput = utf8.encode(input).toString();
  String compComp = utf8.encode(stringwithapostrophe).toString();
  
  print (compInput);
  print (compComp);
  
  if (compInput == compComp) {

 print ('Yes it matches');
    
    } else {

  print ('No it does not');
    }
  
  
}
```

This output's a result of:

```
[99, 104, 97, 116, 110, 117, 109, 46, 116, 120, 116]
[99, 104, 97, 116, 110, 117, 109, 46, 116, 120, 116, 39]
No it does not
```

So how can I remove that last apostrophe from the String?
I've tried `.removeAt` and `.removeLast`.  But I just can't crack this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I applied regex to it.  That sorted it:

```
String filenametosend = (basename(f.toString()))
                             .replaceAll(RegExp(r"[-!$%^&*()+|~=`{}#@\[\]:;'’<>?,\/"
                                 '"”'
                                 "]"), '');
```

Answer (score 0):

This way too:

```
  final apostrophe = '\'';
  final length = stringwithapostrophe.length;
  if (length > 0 && stringwithapostrophe[length - 1] == apostrophe) {
    stringwithapostrophe = stringwithapostrophe.substring(0, length - 1);
  }
```

Or this way (remove all):

```
  final apostrophe = '\'';
  stringwithapostrophe = stringwithapostrophe.replaceAll(apostrophe, '');
```

Remove (any) last:

```
  final length = stringwithapostrophe.length;
  stringwithapostrophe = length > 0
      ? stringwithapostrophe.substring(0, length - 1)
      : stringwithapostrophe;
```